# CSV column values as variables in PHP

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

I have simple csv file:

id | ean

---

1 | 2342342345234

---

2 | 3453453454353

---

I want to have access for this data by variable in foreach loop:
$id = 1, $ean = 2342342345234

Is that possible?

```
<?php
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/products.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
}
fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

Comment: _“Is that possible?”_ - well in the most trivial way, you could simply _assign_ the values to those variables, `$id = $data[0]; $ean = $data[1];` …?

Comment: Question is very unclear. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your delimiter is a pipe, not a comma so change the third parameter of your `fgetcsv`. You can then assign the values statically if you are using the values in current iteration, or use an array for later storage.

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/products.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
          $id = $data[0];
          $ean = $data[1];
```

...

or array:

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("upload/products.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
     while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 10000, "|")) !== FALSE) {
          $ids[] = $data[0];
          $eans[] = $data[1];
```

then use the `foreach` with the `key` to access appropriate pairings.

```
foreach($ids as $key => $id) {
    echo $id . ' ' . $eans[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some sample code to create an associative array.

```
$lines = explode( "\n", file_get_contents( 'input.csv' ) );
$headers = str_getcsv( array_shift( $lines ) );
$data = array();
foreach ( $lines as $line ) {
    $row = array();
    foreach ( str_getcsv( $line ) as $key => $field )
        $row[ $headers[ $key ] ] = $field;

    $row = array_filter( $row );
    $data[] = $row;
 }
```